# React native release APK or IPA is not updating according to my code

Tags: react-native

I have tried making new bundle using command below but still no luck.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

My app is **`expo ejected app`**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about iOS , but on Android try the following

- Clean your build

in your project directory execute

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

- Increase your build number.

go to {ProjectDirectory}/android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
versionCode 1 // increase this value by one
}}
```

- finally build your release

in your project directory execute

```
cd android && gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Tried that but still no luck